# java method that takes in generic class, create new instance of the class and calls its method

Tags: java, generics

I have many email classes, EmailA, EmailB, EmailC, EmailD, EmailE extended from the abstract email class. Every email can auto generate its content, and its content is different between every email classes..

I want to generate x number of message of class EmailXXXXX.

They all have the method, generateRandomMessage, so I want to write a generic method that takes in the class of the Email, and create new instance of the given email class to obtain multiple random message from that email class.

Below is my attempt, and I can't figure out how to write a method that takes in generic class and create new instance of the class and call its method.

Help

```
// Generate X number of message for the given input email class
public void generateEmailData(int numOfMessage, Class<T> emailClass) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfMessage; i++) {
            // Instead of creating generateEmailData method in every email class
            // new EmailA().generateRandomMessage();
            String message = new emailClass.getClass().().generateRandomMessage();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Generics are for improving compile time safety . As such, they are not really appropriate here

Comment: It looks like you should instead take an `Email` object as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should define some type bound to the `T` parameter. Otherwise it will become Object at run-time.

```
class YourClass <T extends BaseEmailClass>
```

Now to instantiate the class :

```
public void generateEmailData(int numOfMessage, Class<T> emailClass) {       
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfMessage; i++) {
            String message = emailClass.newInstance().generateRandomMessage();
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
```

This is assuming `BaseEmailClass` is a common super-class or super-interface of all your `EmailXXXXX` classes which has a `generateRandomMessage()` method.

Comment: Where is this `getInstance()` method of `Class` of which you speak?

Comment: Why would you declare `T` at the class rather than the method level?

Comment: @shmosel I assumed that's what the OP did since T was not declared in the method. Perhaps T is used by multiple methods of that class.

Comment: @Eran one problem though, the generateRandomMessage method is not in the BaseEmail class, but is implemented in the child class

Comment: @OuYe In that case how do you expect to pass different classes to that method and still be able to call the same method on instances of these classes?

Comment: @OuYe, you essentially have a strategy pattern. The BaseEmail class should declare an abstract method `generateRandomMessage` that each child class implements.